# AppEngine deployment error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle

I don’t know what changed. This is an api that I have on AppEngine. For the past two days I have not been able to push. Does anyone know what may be causing this? I am using Android Studio on Mac El Capitan.

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@6c5c4442{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~myapi-mobile/1.123456789034567}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:203)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:133)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:501)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-9f0a91645afbfd1f(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:820)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/editor_005fform_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-9f0a91645afbfd1f(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:820)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: you have compiled sources in higher java version , but where you deploy is , in a environment that runs lower java version

Comment: I don't understand your response. But I am using Java 8 in android studio and that is what I am using in in gradle `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` Do you mind being a bit more specific and actionable? And as far as I know, I don't determine the environment that runs the code: I just deploy on appEngine and what happens after that is not up to me.

Comment: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0, occurs when the byte code is compile in compiled in say jdk 8u101, but your deployment environment is something like 8u90. (101, 90 <= minor versions)

Comment: Does anyone know how to "explicitly set the compiler flags to 7"? I am still having no luck on where to add `-source 1.7 -target 1.7`

Comment: I have set the project byte code to 1.7 and I still see the error from app-engine: `File>Other Settings > Default Settings>Build,Execute,Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Project bytecode version: 1.7` and I also set command line parameters to `-source 1.7 -target 1.7` and then I `Invalidate caches/Restart`. Still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you received:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

just confirms that the JRE used on the Google App Engine cannot handle the bytecode version you tried to run:

52.0 means: **Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex)**

This is indeed cannot be handled, The App Engine currently works with Java7 Runtime ([see doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime)):

> App Engine runs your Java web application using a Java 7 JVM in a safe "sandboxed" environment.

But this is not a blocking issue. The only thing you need to do is just explicitly setting the compiler flags to 7, so that the produced bytecode remains compatible with Java7 JRE:

```
-source 1.7 -target 1.7
```

Comment: Do you mind telling me where in android studio to put these flags? Is it under `File>Other Settings > Default Settings` and then what?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, it does not matter what I set the compiler to. Java will support Java and so the code will compile. However, if I have Java 8 methods, then when app-engine tries to run those methods, it will throw the exception because Java 1.7 does not recognize those methods. So for now I will be looking through the code to see which method may be using Java 1.8 constructs.